# Java regex to match

Tags: java, regex, string

For regex validation of string for 1 or 1_2 or 0_2_3. So it's either a digit or digit_digit with maximum 3 times.
I have tried`[0-4]{1}||([0-4]+[_]+[0-4]){1,3}`
This is not doing the validation correctly.

Comment: `[0-4](_[0-4]){0,2}`

Answer (score 0):

First, you specified two alternate choices separated by `|`:

`[0-4]{1}` matches a single digit in the range 0 - 4, but the `{1}` is totally superfluous since `[0-4]` does the same thing.

Your second choice (after the `|`) is `([0-4]+[_]+[0-4]){1,3}` but `[0-4]+` by itself will match 1 or more (an unlimited number) of digits. The next term, `[_]+` will match one or more `_` characters (but so will just `_+`) and the next term `[0-4]` will match a single digit. This whole group can then be repeated from 1 to 3 times as specified by `{1,3}`. So this would match, for example, **12312311123______4**91293939___8**12___8**, where I have use highlighting to show the three repeating groups.

If I understand what you are trying to match, then your regex should be:

```
^[0-4](_[0-4]){0,2}$
```

1. `^` matches the start of the string.
2. `[0-4]` matches a single digit in the range 0 to 4.
3. `(` starts a capture group that will be repeated.
4. `_` matches a `_`
5. `[0-4]` matches a single digit in the range 0 to 4.
6. ')` completes a capture group started at 3.
7. `{0,2}` denotes that the capture group defined by items 3. through 6. may be repeated 0 to 2 times.
8. `$` matches the end of the string.

The point of having the *anchors* `^` and `$` is to ensure that there are no other extraneous characters in the input string in addition to the characters you are trying to match.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JgJhRi/1/)